# Python: JSON File Format not printing out correctly

Tags: python, json, file, printing, format

I'm trying to develop a parser that extracts data from a json formatted file, but when I was testing out trying to read the file and output its contents it doesn't print the data properly. Disclaimer this is my first time working on json so please go easy. Here are the contents of the file (it's quite dense so I'm only putting in a part of it and some of the values are made up):

```
{
    "jobs" : [
        {
            "jobname" : "workload",
            "groupid" : 0,
            "eta" : 0,
            "elapsed" : 69,
            "job options" : {
                "bs" : "4k",
                "rw" : "randread"
            },
            "read" : {
                "io_bytes" : 2000,
                "bw" : 560,
                "slat_ns" : {
                    "min" : 0,
                    "max" : 0,
                    "mean" : 0
                 }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So now I have python code that opens the json file and returns it as a dictionary. Then it's supposed to iterate through the list:

```
import json
  
# Opening JSON file
f = open('workload.log')
  
# returns JSON object as a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
  
# Iterating through the json list
for i in data['jobs']:
    print(i)

# Closing file
f.close()
```

Here's the link to the code I found online: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/read-json-file-using-python/

Now from my understanding on how the json format works I assume when I print the file contents, the output should be:

```
{'jobname': 'workload', 'groupid': 0, 'eta': 0, 'elapsed': 69, 'job options', 'read'}
```

I think 'job options' would be their own category or at least be printed separately from 'jobname', 'groupid', and etc. However, this is what I get instead:

```
{'jobname': 'workload', 'groupid': 0, 'eta': 0, 'elapsed': 69, 'job options': {'bs': '4k', 'rw': 'randread'}, 'read': {'io_bytes': 2000, 'bw': 560, 'slat_ns': {'min': 0, 'max': 0, 'mean': 0}}
```

There's a lot more data than that but that's the gist of it. They are all printed on one line. Is the formatting wrong? I've used this code on other sample JSON formats and it works just fine. I feel like at least the "job options" and "read" sections in the file should be accessible through the data label like "data['jobs']['job options']" or something. I want to figure out how to print out these sections separately.

Comment: Why are you expecting that? Your code is doing exactly what you tell it to do.

Comment: You can add "indent=4" to your json.dump() to make it look nicer, so you can actually compare before and after. - json.dump(dict, file, indent=4)

Comment: Indeed: why do you think the string representation of a `dict` (this question stopped being about JSON as soon as the call to `json.load` returned successfully) would print the values for some keys but not for others? (There's nothing particularly special about the fact that some of the keys have other `dict`s as their values.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates over each job, and then prints that job, one per line. There's only one job in your example file, so you get one line of output.

Why would you expect the print statement to drop some of the data?

Those subkeys are available, exactly as you expect:

```
for job in data['jobs']:
  # job is now the entire job object you where printing
  print(job['job options'])
  # or make it pretty
  print(json.dumps(job['job options'], sort_keys=True, indent=2))

{
  "bs": "4k",
  "rw": "randread"
}
```